# How to compare an associative array with a hard coded string in PHP

Tags: php, session, associative-array

I am facing problem while comparing an associative array element with a hard coded string. 
I am reading a table and assigning one of the column value to session variable.

file1.php - > this is the page where I am reading DB and fetching rows.

```
$query2 = "select * from igimaster where Userid='$uid2' AND Password='$upswd2'";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2);
$rrows3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2);
$_SESSION['Designation'] = $rrows3['Designation'];
```

Once I go back to my home page I am trying to check if Designation is "Student"

file2.php -> this is my home page. 
CASE1

```
<div id="schedule" style="display: <?php if($_SESSION['Designation]) == "student"){echo 'none';}?>">Schedule</div>
```

I am just trying to hide that particular DIV if user is student. I don't know why it is not working. Control is not going inside IF. And also I would like to add, below statement is working. 
CASE 2

```
<li id="login" style="float:right;display: <?php if (isset($_SESSION['Firstname'])){echo 'none';} ?>">Login</li>
```

Please help me understand why CASE1 is not working in File2.php

Comment: You have syntax errors http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enter code here`Your error problem lies here:

```
<div id="schedule" style="display: <?php if($_SESSION['Designation]) == "student"){echo 'none';}?>">Schedule</div>
```

Find the change:

```
<div id="schedule" style="display: <?php if($_SESSION['Designation'] == "student"){echo 'none';}?>">Schedule</div>
```

Missing `'` and additional `)` in `<?php if($_SESSION['Designation]) == "student")`

Comment: @Kiwi Juicer, still not working. :( I tried after correcting errors.